# MVC 4.5 - simplest authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to enable the simplest authentication on a ASP.NET MVC 4.5 project, but I'm kind of stuck at a point here.

I want to protect some of my controllers with Authentication, so that users need to get by a simple forms login controller mechanism. I've done a custom AuthorizeAttribute which on HandleUnauthorizedRequest is returning the user to my Login controller.
My login controller does a user check, and if user validates ok, it performs a call to:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
```

But that does not set the

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

to true, which I check for in my custom AuthorizeAttribute.

Should I switch to setting a ClaimsPrincipal instead?

Comment: asp.net MVC has built in mechanism to redirect you to the login page if the user is not logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in simple forms authentication. That is what I assume you are using. A recommended approach would be to use:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

> After successful authentication, the FormsAuthenticationModule module populates the current User property with the information for the authenticated user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: HttpContext.User.Identity.Name contains the empty string in my case.

Comment: Did you read the other sections in that MSDN article? There might be more stuff missing

Comment: The article is about ASP.NET I just wonder if the same authentication mechanisms applies for ASP.NET MVC 4.5?..

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.config file (in the root of your web project) you need to configure the forms authentication, example:

```
<system.web>
...
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="∼/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Check if that configuration is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with an OWIN approach. Then I'm MVC 5 ready also.

Check out: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1